# Mongodb: getting a large file using stream

Tags: mongodb, mongoose, gridfs, gridfs-stream

I'm using grid-stream and girdFsStorage library for getting image from mongodb.

I uploaded image to db was okay, but when I tried to get image from db failed.

I expected db.collection at `gfs.files.findOne({ filename: req.params.filename }, (err, file) => {...}`
 but, this.db.collection is returned.
any ideas?

> TypeError: this.db.collection is not a function

Here is my db connect

```
 let db =  mongoose.connect(init.mongoUrl)
  .then(() => console.log('Connected to MongoDB...'))
  .catch(err => console.error(('Could not connect to MongoDB...\n'), err))
```

and this is my code for getting an image from db

```
// Init stream
const gfs = Grid(db, mongoose.mongo);

api.get('/image/:filename', (req, res) => {
    gfs.files.findOne({ filename: req.params.filename }, (err, file) => {
      // Check if file
      if (!file || file.length === 0) {
        return res.status(404).json({
          err: 'No file exists'
        });
       }

      // Check if image
      if (file.contentType === 'image/jpeg' || file.contentType === 'image/png') {
        // Read output to browser
        const readstream = gfs.createReadStream(file.filename);
        readstream.pipe(res);
      } else {
        res.status(404).json({
          err: 'Not an image'
         });
      }
    });
});
```

Answer (score 0):

It was because I didn'use

> gfs.collection('uploads');

on .once('open', () => {...})

```
// Init gfs
let gfs;

conn.once('open', () => {
  // Init stream
  gfs = Grid(conn.db, mongoose.mongo);
  gfs.collection('uploads');
});
```

You can see my example here:
https://github.com/qkreltms/mongodb_simple_file_upload_to_db_example/blob/master/app.js

about .collection() :
https://github.com/aheckmann/gridfs-stream/blob/c394e050d066a5c81c6dcdddad186b08a93d5f1f/lib/index.js#L75